# Can not install onboard graphics driver

Tags: windows, windows-10, intel-graphics, integrated-graphics

Asus z170p  + raedon r9 280x + windows 10 64bit

I can not install intel onboard graphics driver. It says "this computer does not meet minimum requirement". I made sure the driver I downloaded is the correct one for win 10 x64. I also redownloaded / downloaded older drivers but none works.
I have raedon graphics driver installed for my 280x

Comment: Why do you want the Intel driver when the 280x is better?

Comment: On most motherboards, the onboard graphics and an external graphics card cannot both operate concurrently... Typically the BIOS/UEFI will disable the onboard graphics chipset when it sees another GPU, so it is not visible to the OS either, and you can't install drivers for something that isn't there (even though technically, it is physically there).

Comment: Just to add to both comments, you can still install the Intel Graphic Driver if you really want to... just remove the Radeon R9, the OS will pick up the Intel GPU - install the driver - done. And then reinstall the R9 GPU in. But yes as Ramhound stated, why bother having 2 GPU drivers if one of them is disabled due to the R9 exist? Its not like you can use both...

Comment: @Najeeb Taher Since my comment appears to to be the appropriate answer I added it as one. Please accept it if it's satisfactory.

Comment: is there a way to force installation of intel onboard graphics drivers even when it is disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most motherboards, the onboard graphics and an external graphics card cannot both operate concurrently... Typically the BIOS/UEFI will disable the onboard graphics chipset when it sees another GPU, so it is not visible to the OS either, and you can't install drivers for something that isn't there (even though technically, it is physically there).